# Distance from Chevron to Sedom

Tags: rashi, eretz-yisrael, geography, vayera

Rashi (Genesis 19:1, "BaErev") asks rhetorically, וכי כל כך שהו המלאכים מחברון לסדום , implying that it's close from Chevron to Sedom.  But if we assume that Sedom was located where the current Dead Sea is (or thereabouts), it's a distance of some 20 miles, so it *would* take from morning until evening to walk there. If they visited Avraham "Kechom hayom" that implies sometime between 10-2, so how can we say that's tarrying?

Comment: Margalit, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for the intriguing question! I hope you'll stick around and continue reading and posting.

Comment: They're also angels, so they didn't need to walk.

Comment: @Heshy Good point in your comment. But, note that the Torah seems to alternate between referring to them as *malachim* vs. *anashim*. In the verse cited they are called "angels", but, it seems that Rash"i may be implying that they acted like humans.

Comment: Yes.  If they're angels, why does this need a comment.  If they're qua people, then it makes sense that it would take from mid-day to the evening to make a 20 mile journey.

Answer (score 1):

Artscroll Rashi Breishis page 192 brings two explanations. Gur Aryeh says that Biblical Sodom was not at the same location as current-day Sodom. Bereishis Rabbah 50:1 says that the angels are not limited by the constraints of men and could of traveled from Hebron to Sodom instantly.

Comment: Interesting!  How does that fit with the location of Yam HaMelach, though?  Even if you place Sedom on the edge of the Yam HaMelach, it's still pretty far from Chevron.  Unless we say that Yam HaMelach was originally larger than it is now?  Or that it has nothing to do with these destroyed cities?